# Format the excel using python and write in excel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an un-formatted excel sheet as input file. I need to re-arrange and write in the another excel file. I need to calculate the emp working hrs who is working in different project and different client.

Here RAM is working in 1st project alone, but mohan is working in 1st and 2nd project and we have to calculate his working hr of 1st and 2nd.

### Input

[image: Input file]

### Output

[image: Output file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> df  # input dataframe
   Employee Name      Project Client  hours
0            Ram          NaN    NaN    NaN
1            NaN  1st Project    NaN    NaN
2            NaN          NaN    ABC    5.0
3            NaN          NaN    NaN    5.0
4          Mohan          NaN    NaN    NaN
5            NaN  1st Project    NaN    NaN
6            NaN          NaN    DEF   10.0
7            NaN          NaN    DEF   10.0
8            NaN  2nd Project    NaN    NaN
9            NaN          NaN    GEH    1.0
10           NaN          NaN    NaN    1.0
11           NaN          NaN    NaN   11.0
```

For each column except the last one, replace NaN by previous value and move the column to index then drop all rows that are empty. Finally, drop the initial RangeIndex.

```
for col in df.columns[:-1]:
    df[col] = df[col].ffill()
    df = df.set_index(col, append=True)
    df = df.dropna(how="all")
df = df.droplevel(0)
```

```
>>> df  # output dataframe
                                  hours
Employee Name Project     Client
Ram           1st Project ABC       5.0
                          ABC       5.0
Mohan         1st Project DEF      10.0
                          DEF      10.0
              2nd Project GEH       1.0
                          GEH       1.0
                          GEH      11.0
```

**Edit**: Output correct excel file

```
df.set_index("hours", append=True).to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: But the client column is showing the duplicate value in the next cell. In Client we have ABC two times

Comment: `df` is a usable DataFrame for your needs, not an excel file.